# dl4j MultiLayerNetwork does not have a constructor that take NeuralNetConfiguration (version 0.9.1)

Tags: scala, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I'm trying to write a simple `Classifier` example in Scala and looking at the `dl4j` examples a `NeuralNetConfiguration` instance is created (using a builder) and then passed as an argument to a `MultiLayerNetwork` class constructor. However, looking at the source code, `MultiLayerNetwork` does not have any constructor taking a `NeuralNetConfiguration` as an example. It looks like these examples are not up to date. Does anyone know how to do this in the last `dl4j` version?

I've manage to find a work around but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it:

```
val conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
   .seed(seed) 
   .iterations(iterations) 
   .learningRate(1e-6f) 
   .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.CONJUGATE_GRADIENT) 
   .l1(1e-1).regularization(true).l2(2e-4)
   .useDropConnect(true)
   .layer(hiddenLayer)
   .layer(outputLayer)
   .build()
val confs: util.List[NeuralNetConfiguration] = new util.LinkedList();
confs.add(conf)
val builder = new MultiLayerConfiguration.Builder()
builder.setConfs(confs)
val model: MultiLayerNetwork = new MultiLayerNetwork(builder.build())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the examples closer. The NeuralNetConfiguration() is your base parameters, then you list your layers (Look closer at any of the examples) and you finish the builder like that. That will give you a MultiLayerConfiguration.

Comment: I see. I can fix this using .list(hiddenLayer, outputLayer). Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`MultiLayerNetwork` class takes instance of `MultiLayerConfiguration` class as a parameter. You can take a look at [javadocs](https://deeplearning4j.org/doc/org/deeplearning4j/nn/multilayer/MultiLayerNetwork.html#MultiLayerNetwork-org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.MultiLayerConfiguration-). You can create `MultiLayerConfiguration` instance as follows;

```
MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder();
```

Actually, when you call `getConf` of `MultiLayerConfiguration`, it returns `NeuralNetConfiguration`. When you look at the docs, you see that `MultiLayerConfiguration.Builder` is nested class of `MultiLayerConfiguration` and subclass of `MultiLayerConfiguration.Builder` is `NeuralNetConfiguration.ListBuilder`. For more information, you can read [this](https://deeplearning4j.org/multilayer-configuration.html).

**EDIT I**

When you are using DL4J in Scala, just remove the type notations. For example;

```
val conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
val multiLayerNetwork = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf)
```

This should work. Please let me know for any questions, I hope it helps!

Comment: If I do  val conf: MultiLayerConfiguration = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder() then I get a: type mismatch;
 found   : org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder
 required: org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.MultiLayerConfiguration
I'll edit my question to show my work around.

Comment: @PedroAlipio, OK! When you make an update, I'll check it out.